# AutomysqlBackup do not save ALL data

Tags: mysql

I installed on a Debian AutoMySQLBackup

All seems to work fine, I got my daily SQL backup saved in /var/lib/AutoMySQLBackup

Even if I run on command line **automysqlbackup** all works correctly.

I was in need to retrieve some old data, and so I restored one of those daily backup.

And I was surprised and disappointed that some recent data were missing (almost 10 days missing)

I searched on this forum, but didn't found anything related to such behavior of AutoMySQLBackup

I checked if exists a /var/log/AutoMySQLBackup but it doesn't

I finally made manually a mysqldump of my database to check if all my data were correctly dumped, and it works like a charm.

There is no disk limitation, i also have check if I fetched the latest version.

What could be the problem for AutoMySQLBackup ?

Thanks by advance for any help

Comment: it is likelly probable that you will get better answer on http://dba.stackexchange.com